# perl Basics - How does a SHIFT function work

Tags: perl

I'm trying to understand this example of `shift` function. I remember reading that it is supposed to extract (remove and return) the first value, however when trying to execute this piece of code I can see that it returns all the elements from the array:

```
@array = (1..5);
while ($element = shift(@array)) {
  print("$element - ");
}
print("The End\n");
```

Outputs as:

```
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - The End
```

Any explanation is highly appreciated!

Source: TutorialsPoint

Comment: It's doing exactly that... Remove the first element and return it, then every time it gives the next one because the first element was removed. Then, when `@array` is empty, there is no element and the `while` stops.

Comment: My mistake, I realize that just now! Sorry for the lame question :) @Arc676

Comment: Note: The following can't handle arrays with false values (e.g. `0`): `while (my $element = shift(@array)) { ... }`. /// The following can't handle arrays with undefined values: `while (defined( my $element = shift(@array) )) { ... }` /// The following can handle any array: `while (@array) { my $element = shift(@array); ... }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its working same way - remove and return the first value. You are getting all values because of `while loop`.

To understand in easy way, remove the `while loop` from your code.

```
my @array = (1..5);
my $element = shift(@array);
print $element, "\n";
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: Thank you! @serenesat you're right, everytime the loop iterates the elements gets removed and returns, I did not realize it was in a loop(without even exploring the problem I had to post it, absolutely my mistake)